# Too many connections in Exim4

Tags: exim

Some users have complained that they are unable to send emails to us.
In their logs appears the message "Too many concurrent SMTP connections; please try again later.".

Checking our logs, we noticed several messages with the error below:

```
2022-10-18 11:01:40 Connection from [X.X.X.X] refused: too many connections
2022-10-18 11:01:40 Connection from [X.X.X.X] refused: too many connections
2022-10-18 11:01:40 Connection from [X.X.X.X] refused: too many connections
2022-10-18 11:01:40 Connection from [X.X.X.X] refused: too many connections
```

Does this message mean that the IP in question made too many connections, or that at the time it tried to connect there were already enough connections?

I'm trying to check the connections limit on my Exim, but inside the /etc/exim4 folder I can't find any .conf file that has the `smtp_accept_max` property in its content.

If I create more Exim servers to distribute the load, can that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find file by content

```
find . -type f -exec grep "smtp_accept_max" '{}' \; -print
```